# Database dates get stored in local timezone

Tags: magento-1.9, database, timezone, time, datetime

I'm having trouble with a timezone issue and I'm looking for confirmation.

Do dates get stored in the database in UTC. This seems to be th consensus I have found in other posts.

> For example: If an order is made on our website at 14:00:00 (UTC +13)
>   it will that be stored in the database -> created_at as 01:00:00?

I ask this as all my dates in the database (viewed through phpmyadmin) seem to be stored in our local time (UTC +13). Is this correct?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this one to check the actual date and time as it is configured in your Magento

```
$time = Mage::getModel('core/date')->timestamp(time());
$now = date('Y-m-d h:i:s', $time);
echo $now;
```

Comment: at UTC 01:28 output is 2017-02-17 02:28:35( = UTC+1) Our timezone is NZST(UTC+12) but we currently have daylight savings NZDT (UTC+13). Actual time in our locale 2017-02-17 14:28:35